# How can I make Vite split dependencies into a vendor file per entry point without manually writing them? Kinda like Laravel Mix

Tags: vite

I'm trying to make it behave similar to what I had in Laravel Mix. This is my setup:

```js
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default {
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/admin.css',
                'resources/css/public.css',
                'resources/js/admin.js',
                'resources/js/public.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        })
    ]
};
```

If I add `splitVendorChunkPlugin`, I get one vendor file which contains all dependencies in `admin.js` and `public.js`. Is there a way to have each entry point automatically create its own vendor file? So when `admin.js` is called, it imports something like `vendor-admin.js` which contains dependencies found in `admin.js` while `public.js` will import `vendor-public.js` which contains dependencies found in `public.js`.

In other words, I have:

- admin.js, which imports `axios` and `highlight.js`.
- public.js, which imports `vue` and `jszip`.

Vite, with `splitVendorChunkPlugin`, does this:

- vendor.js, which contains, `axios`, `highlight.js`, `vue` and `jszip`.
- admin.js
- public.js

What I want:

- vendor-admin.js, which contains `axios` and `highlight.js`.
- admin.js
- vendor-public.js, which contains `vue` and `jszip`.
- public.js

The exact filenames or folder structure is not super important to me, as long as everything gets resolved when requested.

I've read about `manualChunks` but my understanding is, I'd have to write every dependency in `vite.config.js`, right?